# Remove character in specific column after split using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Using awk on my data I have this result:

### Command:

`$ awk '{split($8,INFO,";"); print $1"\t"$2"\t"INFO[8]}' data.txt`

### Result:

> chr1 1115252246 VMF=0.0426
>
> chr1 115256495 VMF=0.0574
>
> chr1 115256536 VMF=0.0465
>
> chr1 115256579 VMF=0.0574

I'd like to remove the "VMF=" string from my third column using the same AWK code and have it:

> chr1 115252246 0.0426
>
> chr1 115256495 0.0574
>
> chr1 115256536 0.0465
>
> chr1 115256579 0.0574

Thank you!

Comment: Good that you have posted the code which you are trying, please do add the sample of input and expected output too for better understanding of your question too each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `sub(/VMF=/,"",INFO[8]);` between the split and the print.